# sql pivot table with strings

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm using sql 2008 and trying to pivot some data.  [Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4095d)

I have tried but can't figure it out.  What i'd like is to take the data and have it appear like this.

[image]

I would put what i've tried but nothing will run and I can't get it to do both ExamID and score and then pivot the rest.

I've tried something simple like this

> SELECT  *
>   FROM dbo.Results
>   PIVOT
>   (max(Answer)
>   FOR ExamID IN ([19966], [19969])
>   )
>   AS p

but that returns nulls. Anyway some help would be great.
Thanks
shannon

Comment: It should be `for bank in ([15], [16], [17], [18], [19])` not `FOR ExamID IN ([19966], [19969])` when your new columns are the bank values -- see this fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4095d/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use @bluefeet's answer, but in order to match your expected output, you will need to change your sample data as well:

```
create TABLE Results
    (
      ExamID INT
    , Score INT
    , Bank INT
    , Answer CHAR(1)
    );
INSERT  INTO results
        ( ExamID, Score, Bank, Answer )
VALUES  ( 1, 70, 15, 'a' ),
        ( 1, 70, 16, 'a' ),
        ( 1, 70, 17, 'b' ),
        ( 1, 70, 18, 'd' ),
        ( 1, 70, 19, 'c' ),
        ( 2, 81, 15, 'b' ),
        ( 2, 81, 16, 'd' ),
        ( 2, 81, 17, 'c' ),        
        ( 2, 81, 18, 'c' ),
        ( 2, 81, 19, 'c' );
```

**Pivot Query:**

```
select *
from Results
pivot
(
  max(answer)
  for bank in ([15], [16], [17], [18], [19])
) piv
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fbea/1/0)